# Passing increment/decrement operator to a function

Tags: c++, function, argument-passing, pre-increment

I have the same function with the only difference that it will either increment or decrement. I would like to generalize from that.

```
template<typename O>
void f(int& i, O op){
  op(i);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  f(i,operator++);
  f(i,operator--);
  return 0;
}
```

How can I make this work?

my other option is to use functional std::plus or have two functions but I'd prefer this solution if possible. Thank you.

Comment: Just write your own functor. (If you could do this by just writing `operator++`, there would be no need for `std::plus`...)

Comment: I don't think you can do that for native types.

Comment: `f(i,[](int & v) { ++v; });`

Comment: @cdhowie Wouldn't it be wonderful if we could do `f(i, x => x++);`

Comment: @cdhowie `s/int/auto/`, and might also want to return something :)

Comment: @T.C. No on both counts. `auto` does not compile in C++11 because it does not support generic lambdas. (I do not use C++14 in any examples until it is no longer a draft.) And why would I return anything in this case? The return value of `op(i)` is not used, so it's pointless to do so.

Comment: @cdhowie Well, it's no longer a draft....and the return would be to follow the semantics of the built-in. For this particular use case, it would be superfluous, I agree.

Comment: Can someone explain why I can't use `operator++` directly without hacks?

Comment: Also, no one mentionned but i'm just using `std::plus` and modified the code to be `i=op(i);`. that or lambda is a matter of taste.

Answer (score 6):

Simply use a lambda:

```
template<typename O>
void f(int& i, O op){
  op(i);
}

int main() {
  int i;
  f(i,[] (int& x) { ++x; });
  f(i,[] (int& x) { --x; });
  return 0;
}
```

Also it is not clear whether you want post- or preincrement.

As noted by @T.C. if you want to keep the semantics of the normal operator you can add the return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option (there are many possible solutions) that also works pre-C++11:

```
enum OpType { increment, decrement };

template <OpType op> void f(int &i);
template<> void f<increment>(int &i) { ++i; }
template<> void f<decrement>(int &i) { --i; }
```

Usage:

```
f<increment>(i);
```

To keep your codebase tidy you probably want to use some scoping though, so either use a scoped enum in C++11, or a namespace.

Answer (score 1):

in the use case you give, typename O is a unary function with no state, which can be modelled with a simple function pointer:

```
#include <iostream>

int& increment(int& i) {
    ++i;
    return i;
}

int& decrement(int& i) {
    --i;
    return i;
}

template<typename O>
void f(int& i, O op){
    op(i);
}

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    f(i, increment);
    cout << i << endl;

    f(i, decrement);
    cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
0
```